# Create `signature area` for mobile app in dart (flutter)

Tags: mobile, dart, signature, flutter

i want to create a signature area like [Here](https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture) with dart in a mobile app!

I tried to use the [CustomPaint](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) class ... But it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. Add an [mcve] of your code, and describe what problems you're having. _"But it doesn't work"_ isn't very helpful.

Comment: Your program [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: Can the delete voter explain their vote? The answer posted here seems rather helpful....

Comment: [The Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357689/is-this-a-right-question-for-an-audit), @user000001. I agree that deletion is completely unwarranted, given the high quality answer. If it gets deleted anyway, please flag it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can create a signature area using [`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to record touches and [`CustomPaint`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) to draw on the screen. Here are a few tips:

- Use [`RenderBox.globalToLocal`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/globalToLocal.html) to convert the [`DragUpdateDetails`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html) provided by [`GestureDetector.onPanUpdate`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onPanUpdate.html) into relative coordinates
- Use a [`GestureDetector.onPanEnd`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onPanEnd.html) gesture handler to record the breaks between strokes.
- Mutating the same `List` won't automatically trigger a repaint because the [`CustomPainter`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) constructor arguments are the same. You can trigger a repaint by creating a new `List` each time a new point is provided.
- Use [`Canvas.drawLine`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawLine.html) to draw a rounded line between each of the recorded points of the signature.

[image: video]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignaturePainter extends CustomPainter {
  SignaturePainter(this.points);

  final List<Offset> points;

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null)
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
    }
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(SignaturePainter other) => other.points != points;
}

class Signature extends StatefulWidget {
  SignatureState createState() => new SignatureState();
}

class SignatureState extends State<Signature> {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
            Offset localPosition =
                referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

            setState(() {
              _points = new List.from(_points)..add(localPosition);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(null),
        ),
        CustomPaint(painter: SignaturePainter(_points), size: Size.infinite),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(body: new Signature());
}

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new DemoApp()));
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work anymore with the beta channel of flutter. I tried on emulator and on a real device (Pixel 2) but nothing draws on the screen.

Comment: @xrd 
i changed structure a bit, please check the gist here: 
https://gist.github.com/kitttn/408aa1264b82ae8ce1c0098a270e4f52

Comment: @xrd please note you should enable Dart 2 support in your IDE / analyzer. Or just manually add `new` in children constructor invocations.

Comment: @NikitaKraev thank you. How can I make it more performant? If I keep drawing I loose the 60 fps and gets into like 5 fps and becomes very slow. Is there a way to make it more performant. Im creating more like a drawing app. Thank you.

Comment: Refer to @Nikita Kraev  `s link. It works with dart at 2018.5.2, while Collin Jackson answer not.

Comment: I couldn't get this code to run until I modified: `child: new CustomPaint(painter: new SignaturePainter(_points)),` with the replacement `child: CustomPaint(painter: SignaturePainter(_points), size: Size.infinite),`

Comment: I've updated the code with the suggestions in the comments

Comment: @CollinJackson how can I delete the last line? removeLast() doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I had to switch GestureDetector and CustomPaint, otherwiser the onPanUpdate was not triggered

Comment: I would clamp localPostion, so that the signing doesn't overflow the signature widget size : localPosition = Offset(
              localPosition.dx.clamp(0.0, referenceBox.size.width),
              localPosition.dy.clamp(0.0, referenceBox.size.height),
            );