# What is the right way to add a sized PageView in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I try to add a [`PageView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) which doesn't fill the whole screen.

To do that I putted the PageView inside a [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new SizedBox(height: 100.0, child: new Center(child: new Text("sticky header"))),
          new Expanded(
            child: new PageView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                    child: new _Painter(),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                    child: new _Painter(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works so far.

Each `PageView` has a [`_Painter`](https://gist.github.com/the4thfloor/a88a2bfc34814e53cf7406af93d4c415#file-main-dart-L55) which has a [`RenderBox`](https://gist.github.com/the4thfloor/a88a2bfc34814e53cf7406af93d4c415#file-main-dart-L70) to paint something.

And here comes my problem: I use the [`handleEvent`](https://gist.github.com/the4thfloor/a88a2bfc34814e53cf7406af93d4c415#file-main-dart-L91) method to detect drag events but the `y` position is wrong. You can see that the drawn line is not where I touched the screen (the transparent bubble).

[image]

How can I fix this? Do I have to calculate the correct `y` position myself?

You can find the [full source here](https://gist.github.com/the4thfloor/a88a2bfc34814e53cf7406af93d4c415).

**Update**

`globalToLocal` fixed the problem halfway but I still have to include the padding in the calculation. Is there a way to get the padding of a widget?

```
void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  final pos = globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  _currentPath?.lineTo(pos.dx + 50.0, pos.dy + 50.0);
  markNeedsPaint();
}
```

**Bonus Points**

When I drag the `PageView` left and right my `_PainterRenderBox` forgets the drawn lines. Where is the best place to remember this lines? Store them in the `_Painter` or in the `_MyHomePageState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that you are missing is to convert the `globalPosition` into `localPosition` with respect to the `RenderBox`. You can achieve it like

```
// onDragUpdate with the Painting Context
RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
Offset localPosition = referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
// then use the localPosition to draw
```

Example usage for your use case as in [here](https://gist.github.com/the4thfloor/a88a2bfc34814e53cf7406af93d4c415):

```
class _PainterRenderBox extends RenderBox {
  final _lines = new List<Path>();
  PanGestureRecognizer _drag;
  Path _currentPath;

  // variable to store padding
  Offset padding;

  _PainterRenderBox() {
    final GestureArenaTeam team = new GestureArenaTeam();
    _drag = new PanGestureRecognizer()
      ..team = team
      ..onStart = _handleDragStart
      ..onUpdate = _handleDragUpdate
      ..onEnd = _handleDragEnd;
  }

  @override
  bool get sizedByParent => true;

  @override
  bool hitTestSelf(Offset position) => true;

  @override
  handleEvent(PointerEvent event, BoxHitTestEntry entry) {
    assert(debugHandleEvent(event, entry));
    if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
      _drag.addPointer(event);
    }
  }

  @override
  paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    // update padding
    padding = offset;

    final Paint paintBorder = new Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = Colors.white.withAlpha(128);
    canvas.drawRect(offset & size, paintBorder);

    final Paint paintPath = new Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = Colors.white;
    _lines.forEach((path) {
      canvas.drawPath(path, paintPath);
    });
  }

  // check if the point lies inside drawable area
  bool _canDraw(Offset offset){
    return (padding & size).contains(offset);
  }

  void _handleDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    _currentPath = new Path();
    Offset point = globalToLocal(details.globalPosition); // convert globalPosition to localPosition
    point = padding + point; // add the padding to localPosition if any
    // check if point lies inside drawable area and then markNeedsPaint
    if(_canDraw(point)){
      _currentPath?.moveTo(point.dx, point.dy);
      _lines.add(_currentPath);
      markNeedsPaint();
    }
  }

  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    Offset point = globalToLocal(details.globalPosition); // convert globalPosition to localPosition
    point = padding + point; // add the padding to localPosition if any
    // check if point lies inside drawable area and then markNeedsPaint
    if(_canDraw(point)){
      _currentPath?.lineTo(point.dx, point.dy);
      markNeedsPaint();
    }
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    _currentPath = null;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }
}
```

There is a question with a similar use case which allows the user to sign on the screen. Hope that might help you to know how to keep track of path. You can take a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241071/create-signature-area-for-mobile-app-in-dart-flutter/46246111).

Hope that helps!

Comment: That solves the problem halfway. I have a padding around the RenderBox, which has to be included in the calculation. How do I get to the padding without handing it over?

Comment: You receive an `Offset` along with the `PaintingContext` which tells about an padding data. Either add that offset to the points in path during drawing, or add it to the points when you add the points to path.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your code. Hope that helps! Accept the answer if it answered your question.