# How to maintain a 60fps in CustomPainter that paints on user gestures

Tags: dart, flutter

I created a CustomPainter that creates the drawing based on the users gestures. As the user pans across the screen the painting is created. However for complex paintings I loose the 60fps performance and gets into more of a 5fps.

How can I make it more performant. My code just follows the below answer

[Create `signature area` for mobile app in dart (flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241071/create-signature-area-for-mobile-app-in-dart-flutter)

And more importantly exactly the code as below gist

https://gist.github.com/kitttn/408aa1264b82ae8ce1c0098a270e4f52

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ensure my CustomPaint widget painting is stored in the raster cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702376/how-to-ensure-my-custompaint-widget-painting-is-stored-in-the-raster-cache)

Comment: I wrote this guide. You might want to check it out https://jaycoding.tech/tutorials/guides/efficient-sketching-app-using-flutter-icstum