# How to align the dots in a row and column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, flutter-layout

I want to arrange dots like shown in image
And I don't have idea how to repeat this same in a `Row` and `Column`
[image]

Comment: @CopsOnRoad can you answer this?

Comment: did you try to add one column and inside that add 5 rows. Inside rows add those images

Comment: did you try GridView ?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya no, I didnt try GridView

Comment: this could be easily possible with grid view, but that point can't be at the center of screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

There are many ways of doing it like a `Table`, or `Row` and `Column` combined. But `GridView` is the easiest and recommended one.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
      color: Colors.orange,
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 25,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70, shape: BoxShape.circle)),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 40,
          crossAxisSpacing: 50,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked, I am thinking of making a function in which a player (2 player game)draws a line (horizontally or vertically only) by joining dots and whoever completes the fourth side of the square should play again.

when all boxes colored , game ends.            

I am creating logic, when you get something suggest me.

Comment: There are 2 ways of doing it, 1st (easier), try making a border between 2 dots like a tubelight, initially it's color would be light white, and one user taps on it, you can change its color. 2nd way (bit complicated) would be to use `CustomPainter` to allow user to draw line between two dots, and combine this approach with `DragTarget`.

Comment: Actually I want to make simple dot and box game .. So, I am talking about that joinning when a player touches a dot and can draw a line when he reaches another dot . I hope I am able to make you undertand what I want.

Comment: Yes, Prianca I completely got your point, what you need is `CustomPainter` here, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241071/create-signature-area-for-mobile-app-in-dart-flutter) how you can draw lines, the approach you are talking about will require significant amount of time.

Comment: Okay I will see to it and just suggest me what else should I read to do this i will do that too .

Comment: No, you are good with that, however I'll see if I can get enough time, I'll make the solution for you.